# Ajax form handling is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I like to handle a contact form by Ajax. The script should prevent a redirect, clear all the input fields after submitting and should alert some message.

My Form:

```
<form id="contact-form-edc" method="post" action="contact-form.php">
              <div class="full-row fly-in-animation">
                  <div class="large-4 kontakt_left small-12 columns">
                      <label>Anrede
                          <input type="radio" name="anrede" value="Herr" id="herr"><label for="herr">Herr</label>
                          <input type="radio" name="anrede" value="Frau" id="frau"><label for="frau">Frau</label>
                      </label>
                      <label>Name*
                          <input type="text" required name="name">
                      </label>
                      <label>Vorname*
                          <input type="text" required name="vorname">
                      </label>
                      <label>E-Mail*
                          <input type="text" required name="email">
                      </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                      <label>Ihre Nachricht*
                          <textarea rows="10" required name="nachricht"></textarea>
                      </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                      <label><a href="#" data-reveal-id="datenschutzModal">Datenschutz</a> akzeptieren*
                          <input type="checkbox" required name="datenschutz">
                      </label>
                      <input type="submit" class="button radius" value="Abschicken">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </form>
```

And this is my Ajax Script:

```
$(function() {

    // Kontakt-Formular in das Script laden
    var form = $('#contact-form-edc');

    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Den Weiterleitung stoppen
        e.preventDefault();

        // Die Kontakt-Formular Daten in das Script laden
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Das Kontakt-Formular absenden
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })

        return false;

            .done(function(response) {
            // Erfolgreiche Meldung
            alert("erfolg");

            // Das Kontakt-Formular leeren
            $('input').val('');
            $('textarea').val('');
            $('.button').val('Absenden')
        })
            .fail(function(data) {
            // Fehler Meldung
            alert("error");
        });

    });

});
```

On other sites this code snippets work very well. You can have a look on my [site](http://www.edc.headonline.de/#kontakt-jumper)...

Comment: Your `form` variable is a jQuery obect. You don't need to do `$(form)`

Comment: Thank you! Still not working...

Comment: What *is* happening? I see what you say should he going on but what is it doing instead? Any error messages?

Comment: No error – Nothing. The form redirects to the PHP Page and no alert appears.

Comment: You should move `return false` to the end of the function. It looks like you have it in a spot that is completely wrong.

Comment: The Ajax is working very well on other sites. This is weird...

Comment: There are a lot of syntax errors (probably). I see at least one. A `.done(function(response)` that's not connected to any object.  `return false;.done(function(response)` is not gonna work.  That ain't how the dot operator works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works great. just remove the `return false;` from your jQuery script.

here is my test.

I add a div for the server response at the end of the form.

form.php:

```
<form id="contact-form-edc" method="post" action="contact-form.php">
              <div class="full-row fly-in-animation">
                  <div class="large-4 kontakt_left small-12 columns">
                      <label>Anrede
                          <input type="radio" name="anrede" value="Herr" id="herr"><label for="herr">Herr</label>
                          <input type="radio" name="anrede" value="Frau" id="frau"><label for="frau">Frau</label>
                      </label>
                      <label>Name*
                          <input type="text" required name="name">
                      </label>
                      <label>Vorname*
                          <input type="text" required name="vorname">
                      </label>
                      <label>E-Mail*
                          <input type="text" required name="email">
                      </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                      <label>Ihre Nachricht*
                          <textarea rows="10" required name="nachricht"></textarea>
                      </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="large-4 small-12 columns">
                      <label><a href="#" data-reveal-id="datenschutzModal">Datenschutz</a> akzeptieren*
                          <input type="checkbox" required name="datenschutz">
                      </label>
                      <input type="submit" class="button radius" value="Abschicken">
                  </div>
                  <div id="res">response: </div>
              </div>
          </form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    // Kontakt-Formular in das Script laden
    var form = $('#contact-form-edc');

    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        // Den Weiterleitung stoppen
        e.preventDefault();

        // Die Kontakt-Formular Daten in das Script laden
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        // Das Kontakt-Formular absenden
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })



            .done(function(response) {
            // Erfolgreiche Meldung
            alert("OK!");
            $('div#res').append(response); /*THIS LINE ADDED*/

            // Das Kontakt-Formular leeren
            $('input').val('');
            $('textarea').val('');
            $('.button').val('Absenden')
        })
            .fail(function(data) {
            // Fehler Meldung
            alert("error");
        });

    });

});
```

And finally contact-form.php just a simple line:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['name'];
?>
```

and it works!